# How to run app via script in package.json?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a script like below in my package.json:

```
"start:dev": "nest start MYSQL_PORT=3306 MYSQL_HOST=localhost MYSQL_USERNAME=root MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb MYSQL_PASSWORD=",
```

why, when i run `npm run start:dev` my app is crashed with this error:

```
[Nest] 2264   - 02.01.2021, 19:01:10   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +120ms
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I have a databse o `Xaamp` without using `password`,

my typeorm config to db:

```
 type: 'mysql',
 host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
 port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT ? +process.env.MYSQL_PORT : 3306,
 username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
 password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD || '',
 database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
```

thanks for any helps

Comment: have you tried this: `"MYSQL_PORT=3306 MYSQL_HOST=localhost MYSQL_USERNAME=root MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb MYSQL_PASSWORD= nest start"` just guessing

Comment: i do it and i got `'MYSQL_PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Windows, try moving the environment variables before the `nest start` command and add `SET` before each environment variable.

```json
"start:dev": "SET MYSQL_PORT=3306 && SET MYSQL_HOST=localhost && SET MYSQL_USERNAME=root && SET MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb && SET MYSQL_PASSWORD= && nest start",
```

Comment: i do it and i got `'MYSQL_PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Try adding `set` before `MYSQL_PORT` like this: `"start:dev": "set MYSQL_PORT=3306`

Comment: i added and it not work, after launch is only showed a full script like `> SET MYSQL_PORT=3306 MYSQL_HOST=localhost MYSQL_USERNAME=...`

Comment: I just updated my answer, can you try again with my updates?